# LTSpice Vcesat Parameter Transistor

Tags: ltspice

I would like to use a transistor in LTSpice and I don't want to choose a specific one but keep the NPN with parameters added to the model. So basically, my command would be : .model Q NPN(..). I would like to set the Vcesat parameter but it doesn't seem to appear as a parameter on LTSpice's model of transistor. Does anybody know how to fix Vcesat ? 
Thank you for your answer and time !

Comment: Did you try Vceo as parameter?

Comment: Doesn't seem to really change anything. Plus it's not in the list of parameters that LTSpice gives for transistors..

Comment: You need to show the **entire** text of the default LTspice model. We need to see what kind of model is being used before we can talk about appropriate model **parameters**.

Comment: See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/42210/95619) question and, in particular, [Oli Glaser's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/42218/95619). Be sure to read the document he linked. It's really not that simple, but not that complicated, either. But if you're expecting to change a parameter and be done with it, you're out of luck.

Comment: There are 3 pages of parameters for LTSpice transistor model from page 147 to page 150 on this help doc for LTSpice : http://rincon-mora.gatech.edu/classes/ltspice.pdf  
Yes I was expecting to maybe link one of the parameters from this pages to Vcesat but doesn't seem to work that easily..